# CABasicAnimation Not Changing Stroke Color

Tags: ios, swift, cabasicanimation

I have the following code in my viewDidLoad() to draw a circle and then animate the color change of its stroke:

```
let leftCirclePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 32, y: view.bounds.height-30), radius: CGFloat(20), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi*2), clockwise: true)
leftShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
leftShapeLayer.path = leftCirclePath.cgPath
leftShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
leftShapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
leftShapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0
view.layer.addSublayer(leftShapeLayer)

let leftAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeColor")
leftAnimation.fromValue = UIColor.white.cgColor
leftAnimation.toValue = UIColor.red.cgColor
leftAnimation.duration = 1
leftAnimation.repeatCount = 5
leftAnimation.autoreverses = true
leftShapeLayer.add(leftAnimation, forKey: "strokeColor")
```

The shape is drawn fine, but there's no color change of its stroke. Does anyone know what the issue could be? Thanks.

Comment: Does anything happen if you change `strokeColor` for `fillColor`?

Comment: Yes, it changes fine

Comment: I've copy-pasted your code (only added `let` on line#2 and I'm seeing the stroke animating. Maybe the number of repeats (5) are already performed when you put the View on screen?

Comment: You're right, I jacked up the number of repeats and it works now. Thanks!